# Proving that $\min \{ \|x-x_0\|:x\in F\} = \max \{ | \langle x_0,y \rangle| : y \in F^{\perp} , \|y\|=1 \}$, if $H$ is Hilbert, $F$ a closed subspace

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

So, I need to prove that $\min \{ \|x-x_0\|:x\in F\} = \max \{ | \langle x_0,y \rangle| : y \in F^{\perp} , \|y\|=1 \}$, if $H$ is a Hilbert space, $F$ is a proper linear subspace of $H$ and $x_0 \in H \setminus F$. 
First of all, I know that $x_0$ can be written as $x_0 = x_1 + x_2$, $x_1 \in F$ and $x_2 \in F^{\perp} $, in a unique way, where $\|x_1-x_0\| = \min \{ \|x-x_0\|:x\in F\}$. I have proven that $|\langle x_0,y \rangle| \leq \|x_1-x_0\|$, so $\max \{ | \langle x_0,y \rangle| : y \in F^{\perp} , \|y\|=1 \} \leq \min \{ \|x-x_0\|:x\in F\}$.
The problem is I can't prove that $\min \{ \|x-x_0\|:x\in F\} \leq \max \{ | \langle x_0,y \rangle| : y \in F^{\perp} , \|y\|=1 \} $. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint : take  $y = x_2 /\|x_2\|$

Comment: Hint: Decompose as $x_0=x_1+x_2$ with $x_1 \in f$ and $x_2 \in F^\perp$. For the left hand side, write the norm squared as the inner product with itself and expand out. Arrive at a lower bound (in terms of $\|x\|$) using Cauchy-Schwarz. You will find that the left hand side can be computed explicitly (in terms of $x_1$ and $x_2$) by finding the vertex of an upward opening parabola.

The right hand side is similar. Find an upper bound using Cauchy Schwarz. Show that an element achieves this upper bound. You will find the left hand side and the ride hand side are equal.